# vuejs file upload to different destinations

Tags: vue.js

specify upload location / parameters for different upload buttons for this code:
https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader

from the example: https://github.com/simple-uploader/vue-uploader

ive changed:

```
<uploader :options="options" class="uploader-example">
```

to:

```
<uploader :options="{target : '//localhost:3000/upload?test=123'}" class="uploader-example">
```

which works, but you cannot have two "uploader's" on the page.
theres probably a way to pass parameters in via attrs in here:

```
<uploader-btn :attrs="attrs">
```

but how do you read the parameters and create a differnt url from it?

expected:
two upload buttons, one with target url:

```
localhost:3000/upload?test=123
```

and one with:

```
localhost:3000/upload?test=ABC
```

it would be easier if the code itself calls a function inside the users code for uploading where one could read parameters instead of just ŕeading one global url for uploading.

Also what i don't get is this, since simple-uploader/vue-uploader was installed like this:

```
npm install vue-simple-uploader --save
```

shouldn't this:

```
find ~/.npm  -name '*.vue' | grep upload
```

or this in my project dir:

```
find .  -name '*.vue' | grep upload
```

now show the .vue file containing uploader?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you should be able to have two uploader components on a single page; it's just a simple Vue component. Can you post a simple project that shows that two uploaders will not work?

Comment: youre right, i did put each uploader inside a <div> so i had two divs at the same level inside <template> which is not allowed. just read the error wrong. please post your suggestion as answer.